# MySQL Query -> Finding a record with two conditions in child table

Tags: mysql

I have two simple databases:

**Customers:**

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id |           customer       |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Dent, Arthur             |
|  2 | Prefect, Ford            |
|  3 | Beeblebrox, Zaphod       |
+----+--------------------------+
```

**Purchases:**

```
+-------------+--------------------------+
| Customer ID |  SKU       |  Date       |
+-------------+--------------------------+
|     1       | PRODUCT1   | 2016-01-16  |
|     1       | PRODUCT3   | 2016-01-18  |
|     2       | PRODUCT2   | 2015-12-12  |
|     2       | PRODUCT1   | 2016-02-10  |
|     3       | PRODUCT3   | 2016-03-01  |
+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is construct a query that returns any customers who have bought both PRODUCT1 and PRODUCT3 (so in the example above, that should just be Arthur Dent).

I can easily select for one product; e.g.

```
SELECT `Customer ID` FROM `Customers` a LEFT JOIN `Purchases` b 
ON a.`Customer ID` = b.`Customer ID` WHERE `SKU`=`PRODUCT1'
```

... but I can't figure out how to only select records in "Customers" where there are corresponding records in "Purchases" that match two SKUs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways to do this.  One is to use aggregation and one is to `join` to the `purchases` table multiple times:

```
select c.customer
from customer c
   join purchases p1 on c.id = p1.customerid and p1.sku = 'PRODUCT1'
   join purchases p2 on c.id = p2.customerid and p2.sku = 'PRODUCT3'
```

Depending on your data, you may need to use `distinct` with this to eliminate duplicates.

---

Here's an alternative with aggregation:

```
select c.customer
from customer c
where exists (
   select 1
   from purchases p
   where sku in ('PRODUCT1','PRODUCT2')
       and c.id = p.customerid
   having count(distinct sku) = 2
)
```

Comment: Fantastic, the first suggestion did the job perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via couple of `exists` clauses, e.g.:

```
select c.id, c.customer
from customer 
where exists (
 select customer_id from purchases 
 where customer_id = c.id and sku = 'PRODUCT1'
)
and exists(
 select customer_id from purchases 
 where customer_id = c.id and sku = 'PRODUCT3'
);
```